# CentOS 7.3 with Gnome 3.14 - Allowing any user to join Wireless network before authenticating remotely

Tags: centos, wifi, gnome3

I am trying to allow users of a laptop to be able to connect by hand with their own credentials to our secure wireless so then they can proceed to authenticate remotely.

[image: Lock Screen Status Bar Panel]

My initial thoughts were to grant/allow users to utilise the Status Bar dropdown menu (see screenshots below) even on lock screen to join the wireless, much like they would once they are logged in:

[image: Status Bar Panel once logged in]

However after extensive research I have not been able to come up with a solution to this.

All input appreciated and of course let me know what you think, or if I am on the wrong tracks to solve this problem.